# Jquery animate вызов одного callback

Tags: jquery, callback, animate, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть 3 блока:

```
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
```

И js код:

```
$('.test').animate({height: '100px'},function(){alert('callback');});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вызвать callback один раз в конце всей анимации, а не для каждого элемента набора?

Comment: Как вариант, пометить последний элемент в анимации, и пока не попался он ретурнить из CallBack функции, вот примерчик http://jsfiddle.net/7z5gfn81/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться .promise(), тем более в jquery это уже реализовано.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.when( $('.test').animate({height: '100px'}) ).done(function() {
        alert('готово');
    });
});
```

Рабочий пример https://jsfiddle.net/97c9wndb/

Подробнее https://api.jquery.com/promise/ и, например, http://www.tomauger.com/2014/web-development/using-promises-in-asynchronous-jquery-animate-calls